# Sorting a bigint[] column in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update, biginteger, unnest

I have a table that has a `bigint[]` column of unsorted bigint's. There doesn't seem to be a bigintarray extension like the intarray extension.

I'm trying to write a simple UPDATE query that will update all columns in place and sort the values ASC, and have been coming up dry. Alas, I ask the world.

**Current**

```
id | my_big_int_column

1  | {22222222222222222, 11111111111111111}
```

**Expected after Update**

```
id | my_big_int_column

1  | {11111111111111111, 22222222222222222}
```

Thanks any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what is the datatype of this column, is this `bigint[]`?

Comment: Yes the column is of the type bigint[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a subquery that unnest the array and aggregates it back with the proper order:

```
update mytable
set my_big_int_column = (
    select array_agg(val order by val) 
    from unnest(my_big_int_column) as v(val)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a9b0a9b4f3a82b71bf8d4dd5d78b8469)**